# Python.expat can't parse XML file with bad symbols. How to go around?

Tags: python, xml, unicode, expat-parser

I'm trying to parse an XML file (OSM data) with expat, and there are lines with some Unicode characters that expat can't parse:

```
<tag k="name"
v="абвгдежзиклмнопр�?туфхцчшщьыъ�?ю�?�?БВГДЕЖЗИКЛМ�?ОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЬЫЪЭЮЯ" />

<tag k="name" v="Cin\x8e? Rex" />
```

(XML file encoding in the opening line is "UTF-8")

The file is quite old, and there must have been errors. In modern files I don't see UTF-8 errors, and they are parsed fine. But what if my program meets a broken symbol, what workaround can I make? Is it possible to join bz2 codec (I parse a compressed file) and utf-8 codec to ignore the broken characters, or change them to "?"?

Comment: What the <?XML encoding from the first line?

Comment: Sounds like a character set issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if '�' characters were introduced by copy-pasting string here,
but if you have them in original data, then it seems to be generator
problem which introduced \uFFFD charactes as:

"used to replace an incoming character whose value is unknown or
unrepresentable in Unicode"

citied from:
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm

Workaround? Just idea for extension:

```
good = True
buf = None
while True:
if good:
        buf = f.read(buf_size)
        else:
        # try again with cleaned buffer
        pass
        try:
            xp.Parse(buf, len(buf) == 0)
            if (len(buf) == 0):
                    break
        good = True
    except ExpatError:
        if xp.ErrorCode  == XML_ERROR_BAD_CHAR_REF:
            # look at ErrorByteIndex (or nearby)
            # for 0xEF 0xBF 0xBD (UTF8 replacement char) and remove it
            good = False
        else:
            # other errors processing
            pass
```

Or clean input buffer instead + corner cases (partial sequence at the buffer end).
I can't recall if python's expat allows to assign custom error handler.
That would be easier then.

If i clean yours sample from '�' characters it's processed ok.
\xd1 does not fail.

OSM data?

Comment: Yes, it's OSM whole earth dump. I'll try to make a generator of your code, thanks!

Comment: I've noted that xp.ErrorCode contains a numeric code, but XML_ERROR_BAD_CHAR_REF contains a string (Python 2.6). That's quite a headache if I want to check error type: I'll need to compare strings, etc.

Comment: Well... this doesn't work: when expat raises an error, it has already eaten the characters up to that, and I can't see a way to get the index of wrong character in `buf`. There's only `lineno` and `columnno`, and character counter that counts _all_ characters in the file, but not in `buf`.

Comment: So then try another thing i've posted. Cleanup buffer after read.
Also check buffer end for partial sequences, if so: remove that
part to 'reminder' storage, which will be merged with next buffer
readed.
One more thing: have your input data those '�' character, or expat
reports on other thing?
I've checked my planet-100129.osm with expat 2.0.1 but in C++ app
(only half our) and there were no characters error (file decompressed). Can you try this on uncompressed file adn see if you
have the same errors?